# is there any possible way to create a date range validation with two different ngx date picker fields using angular 10?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzp9j.png)

in the figure below, I want to prevent the user from selecting past date value in end date picker if he choose a start date

Comment: Hi you can make this question more descriptive on what you tried as well. Also to achieve what you want, if the date-picker accepts a minimum date as input , set the minimum date of end-date-picker to the one set by the start date-picker to ensure it's always equal or greater.

Comment: Can you share your code here

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a custom validation method that accepts date controls. The start date would use end date as well start date to compare and validate accordingly. Something similar to

```
createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      dateTo: ['', Validators.required ],
      dateFrom: ['', Validators.required ]
    }, {validator: this.dateLessThan('dateFrom', 'dateTo')});
  }

  dateLessThan(from: string, to: string) {
   return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    let f = group.controls[from];
    let t = group.controls[to];
    if (f.value > t.value) {
      return {
        dates: "Date from should be less than Date to"
      };
    }
    return {};
   }
 }
```